# A Logic Error, A skipping of an **If...Then**

Tags: vb.net

First, I hope you will forgive me as this is my second post and first question; second I am a hack programmer, meaning I find code hack it and then adopt it.

This is a VB program written on VS2010. This is mainly a drop through program style. Very much like a Pachinko machine.

I have a particularly troubling logic error. it is an **If...then** statement.

```
            If intTrinaryStarOrbit <= intBinaryStarOrbit Then
                intTrinaryStarOrbit = intBinaryStarOrbit + 1
            End If
```

The problem comes when then program skips this, even thought intTrinaryStarOrbit is less than intBinaryStarOrbit.

I have stepped through this code so many times I have forgotten to count. I have seen the program step right over this code.

This happens about ever 14 runs through the code.

The next problem is not knowing what part of the code you want to see, as there is 129 pages of rem code. I do not want to spam this post so I have not posted the code. I do have a pastebin account but again I am unsure how to post what you would need to see.

Please let me know what I need to do to receive help.

Thanks from a clueless hack
Seaeagle23

Comment: You're going to have to come up with a [MCVE]. It is beyond reason to think that the `If` statement itself is failing. Need to know what logic preceeds this particular `If` if you want to troubleshoot why it's not being used.

Comment: What's the data type of both variable (intTrinaryStarOrbit, intBinaryStarOrbit) and what are there value when it doesn't go inside the if statement? Are these variable shared with multi threads?

Comment: `129 pages of rem code` What does that mean?  Code that is commented out?  if so it is not applicable at all.  If/when the If Statement executes, it wont execute again until `intBinaryStarOrbit` is incremented or the other is decremented.

Comment: well thank you all for your swift replies.

Comment: well thank you all for your swift replies  i will edit my rems and post what code i do have.  the variables are not shared but public. I will remove the 129 pages of rem, they are procedural comments so i know what needs to be coded.   **http://pastebin.com/ZrNScRmk** is my code.    Sorry for not doing that earlier.

Comment: Not much to go on here. If the application is multi-threaded, it can appear to defy logic as you step through the code, when in fact, its working as designed.

Comment: i dont think it is multi-threaded. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: You don´t really expect anyone to go thru your `2142` loc to find a possible multi-threading error ?!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code and output a message box to show the values then decide on your course of action.

```
   If intTrinaryStarOrbit <= intBinaryStarOrbit Then
            intTrinaryStarOrbit = intBinaryStarOrbit + 1
   Else
       msgbox("Here are the values, TriStar: " & intTrinaryStarOrbit & " BinStar: " & intBinaryStarOrbit 

   End If
```

find out what is in the variables when it is not entering the true condition.

Comment: all the Subs are called through the Sub at the bottom called "Game Engine" the statement works most of the time correctly but i get one that comes in and the value of intTrinaryStarOrbit  is truely less than intBinaryStarOrbit but the if statement gets stepped over by the program.

Comment: hey I just ran the code again and the intTrinaryStarOrbit =3 and intBinaryStarOrbit =18. The code just skipped over it again

Comment: i did dome recoding...when i convert the string to an integer and do the math it works...but when i do the math with strings sometimes it skips the if...is there a difference between string math and integer math???

Comment: @seaeagle23 Yes... you *can't* do math with strings. Think of the comparison operator for strings as being what you'd use to sort names alphabetically. It doesn't work to compare numbers. For your sample code in your question it would have been very helpful if we knew the types up-front. Naming a string variable `intTrinaryStarOrbit` makes us think it's an integer when in reality it's not an integer at all.

Comment: Post the variable definitions and any code that assigned the a value to the variable. If the variable is assigned a value from user input you will need to validate it, if it is coming from a database it should have been validated before it was stored, what are the database column types?